# How to add object in SerializeField in Uinty3D using C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm adding `TMP_InputFields` as a child with button using `Instantiate`. I have `SeriazlizeField` and it contains those input fields. How can I manage to add those new added input fields in this serializefield via script. Here's my code:

```
public GameObject settings;
public TMP_InputField addedPlayer;
public static int playerCount = 5;

[SerializeField]
public TMP_InputField[] names;

public void Plus(){
    playerCount++;
    TMP_InputField added = Instantiate(addedPlayer, settings.transform);
    added.name = "Name" + playerCount;
    //How to add this new added objects in names field
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- replace `TMP_InputField[]` with the `List<TMP_InputField>`
- use `names.Add(yourInstantiatedObject)`